# How to use OpenCL in OpenCV for Python?

Tags: python, opencv, opencl

I have created a simple face detection program which uses Haar Cascade to detect faces. My code as follows:

```
def main():
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while 1:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        img = rescale_frame(frame, percent=50)

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

        bColor = (255,0,0)
        gColor = (0,255,0)
        rColor = (0,0,255)
        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            if (len(faces)%3 == 0):
                cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),rColor,2)
            if (len(faces)%3 == 1):
                cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),gColor,2)
            if (len(faces)%3 == 2):
                cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),bColor,2)

        cv2.imshow('Detected face',img)
        k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
        if (k == 27) or (k == 13):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I would like to execute **face_cascade.detectMultiScale()** on the GPU instead. 
Could anyone advise how I can use the OpenCL directive for PythonOpenCV to achieve that?

I tried following OpenCL for OpenCV: https://opencv.org/platforms/opencl.html and https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/ocl/doc/introduction.html but the examples for Python integration is ridiculously limited.

Comment: If you're using OpenCV-3.x then the architecture has been changed to [Transparent API](https://opencv.org/platforms/opencl.html). Just use `cv::UMat` instead of `cv::Mat` and if you've an OpenCL supported on GPU on your platform then OpenCV will automatically use it.

Comment: Arent those samples for C? i am looking for the same on python.